# ubuntu 20.04 wifi connection is bad and not stable

Tags: drivers, 20.04, wireless, network-manager, connection

I know that there are questions about this but I tried all those answers but my problem is not disappeared. The problem is, when I go to the additional drivers, there I can see the wifi device Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter and it says "This device is not working". In my problematic case, the option 2 which is "Do not use the device" is chosen. When I switched to the option 1: Using DKMS source for the Realtek 8821C PCIe Wifi driver from rtl8821ce-dkms (open source) and apply changes and reboot, ubuntu cannot see the device.

I tried removing and reinstalling the driver, editing the file /etc/nsswitch.conf, editing /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml.

But I am not sure about I did the last one correct becuase the command wasn't like this in the tutorial that I saw in youtube. It was /etc/netplan/00-install something. But I had 01-network-manager-all.yaml in netplan directory I edited that.

My 01-network-manager-all.yaml was this before I changed:
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

I changed it to:

network:
ethernets:
wlp2s0:
dhcp4: true
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

Please help me about this I am new in ubuntu and I am trying my best but I cant find a solution so far.

And I am wondering if I go back to windows and install the correct drivers, does this problem disappear? My laptop came with ubuntu when I bought it.